# Liquibase returning ORA-00907 with SQL using Oracle comment notation (double dash)

Tags: oracle, liquibase

Running SQL on Oracle through Liquibase and getting error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

The SQL we're running has double dashes `--` which can also represent comments in PLSQL.   I'm guessing this is the issue.  Should this be escaped somehow?

```
delete from mytable B where B.NAME in ('XXX--YYY', 'AAA--BBB');
```

Comment: It is most likely interpreted (falsely) as comment. Try with this *"escape"* `'XXX-'||'-YYY'`

Comment: That's a nice workaround it worked.  Please copy that to an answer...

Comment: glad to help, I thought this is very silly approach;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of the characters `--`is most likely interpreted as a comment, so the following charactes until the end of the line are ignored.

You may use following workaround, simple splitting the string in two parts

Instead of

```
'XXX--YYY'
```

use

```
'XXX-'||'-YYY'
```

Do not forget, if you have more dashes, you must repeat stis step , e.g. for `---` you must split the string in three part.

Posible similar problem would be for string containing the multiline comment:

```
'XXX/*YYY', 'XXX*/YYY'
```

Comment: This worked well as a workaround.  Maybe it is silly but it works and I don't know any other solutions so accepting this as the best answer !

Comment: You are right, when the Liquibase wrongly interprets the comments, this is probaly the only possible solution!